# How can I transfer an json file into an embed on discord.py?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I tried this:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role('KING')
async def list(ctx):

    with open(r'F:\DiscordBot\PyCharm\Knastwärter\knastusers.json', 'r')as read_file:
        users = json.load(read_file)

    embedlist = discord.Embed(title='__**Liste aller Häftlinge**__', description=
                              f'{users}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embedlist)
```

But I got this:

```
{'369910055665008652': 'Scuux#0001', '605948244282834944': 'test12312424#3354'}
```

But I want the usernames and IDs to be arranged one below the other, without strings and tail brackets.

Comment: Do you understand what `json.load` actually did? Are you familiar with string formatting? Can you describe a step-by-step process that transforms the input into the output you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not going to transfer json file itself, or your code may be seen like this:

```py
@bot.command(name='file')
async def cmd_file(ctx):
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File('./a.json'))
```

Your problem is how to transfer the information in the json file, so I think you need `Embed.add_field` to achieve this:

```py
@bot.command(name='list')
async def cmd_list(ctx):
    with open('./a.json', 'r') as read_file:
        users = json.load(read_file)

    embedlist = discord.Embed(title='Title', description='User List')

    join = lambda x: '\n'.join(x)
    embedlist.add_field(name='User Name', value=join(users.values()))
    embedlist.add_field(name='User ID', value=join(users.keys()))

    await ctx.send(embed=embedlist)
```

Note that `list` is a built-in data type, you should avoid naming your function as `list`. I suggest you put a prefix to your function name and using `name` argument to `bot.command`.

The result:

[image: Results]

You can adjust to what you like, there are more detail in [documentation of discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed), including lots of methods to beautify your embed.