# How to write all names from Json file in discord.py embed in one value with one title

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, bots

My code

```
@Bot.command()
async def nicknames(ctx, *, message:str=None):

   embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Profile Details", description="nicknames", 
   color=discord.Color.green())
   uuid = MojangAPI.get_uuid(f"{message}")
   profile = MojangAPI.get_profile(uuid)
   people = requests.get('https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/' + uuid + '/names' )
   people_json  = people.json()
   length = len(people_json)
   for length in range(length):
      embed.add_field(name="nicknames", value=people_json[length]["name"], inline=True)

   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3KSk.png)
code result, but i need all names in one value and with one title
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nl7f.png)

here i found the result for my code
[How can I transfer an json file into an embed on discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61899950/how-can-i-transfer-an-json-file-into-an-embed-on-discord-py)
But the code not working

Comment: So do you want them to be under each other like in the second screenshot?

Comment: _But the code not working_ What does that mean? Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: @Chuaat yes, i wand to be unter like in the second screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a new line in a string, use `\n`. That means

```py
print("First Line!\nSecond Line")
```

outputs

```
First Line!
Second Line
```

You can use this to get the nicknames in one field:

```py
names = ""
for i in range(length):
    names = names + "\n" + people_json[i]["name"] #add \n and the person to the string
embed.add_field(name="Nicknames", value = names, inline=True) #add the field
```

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it works so others can see that it works @Estol?